# Node.js request error statuscode 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting the statuscode 403 when I run this code. I'm trying to make authentication with instagram.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
    url:'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/',
    auth: {
       username:'username',
       password:'password'
    }
};
request.post(options, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: A 403 status code in scraping means that your IP was banned, so I'm guessing it means that your IP was banned or your login isn't being authenticated, most likely your login is not being authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Manage clients under instagram/developer. Then click edit under your app and uncheck Disable Implicit OAuth. It will now work as intended.

Comment: I’m sorry, where Can I find this? On the actual account or?

Comment: it is under your Instagram developer account.

Comment: please follow this article. https://medium.com/@vshelestovskyi/instagram-authentication-with-node-js-and-mongodb-edfb7b6065ad